# Unit testing with Jest without module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I have a script that holds a single `const` variable which holds all of my logic, kind-of like Moment.js.
I want to test out functions that go out with this script with Jest.

I can't use `module.exports` since it will not work when I publish my script.
And if I can't use `module.exports` I can't use `require`.

But I still want to run unit tests on my script.
I have tried using `import` with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
import 'src/library.js';

test('Something', () => {
    expect(library.add(1,2)).toBe(3);
});
```

And this is my library:

```
const library = () => {
    return {
        add : (num1,num2) => num1 + num2,
        subtract : (num1,num2) => num1 - num2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what about wrapping your exports with:

```
if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = { yourWhatever };
}
```

Comment: Great one. It will be helpful when the client does not approve of us using other libraries like Webpack and Babel or for any other reason.

Caveat: It looks like a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

First Option (Quick & Dirty):
Don't import.  Just move the code into one file.

Second Option (Best Long Term):
Learn how to use (webpack and) [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Come to think of it, I could use gulp to merge both files (test one and library one).

Comment: Neither of these options solve the original problem asked within constrains asked.